# What cryptography does Monero utilize?

Tags: cryptography

Just looking for a brief explanation of what cryptography is used and where/how it is used in Monero. Thanks :)

Comment: Similar question here: http://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/694/what-cryptographic-assumptions-is-monero-based-on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [Wiki article on CryptoNote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CryptoNote) explains it better than anyone could do in the confines of a Stackexchange reply.

The Proof-of-Work algorithm is called CryptoNight and has several distinct differences/improvements over the earlier SHA256 algorithm used by Bitcoin and clones.

edit: This looks more like an [actual specification](https://cryptonote.org/cns/cns008.txt)

Comment: Monero uses ed25519 to synthesize a public key from a private key. Bitcoin uses secp256k1 to synthesize a public key from a private key.